# Getting Bad Request and Forbidden when sending Notifications in MS teams Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am sending the notification to around 50k users, and I noticed two different errors are getting logged in error logs for very few users.

The two errors are

`Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`

`Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'`

I am not able to understand why this error coming for only few users.

I have tried one way, where I blocked my bot and send a notification to myself then `Forbidden` error got logged.

Is there any other reasons why these two error occurs while sending the message to the users.

**Edit:-**
For Forbidden error
`at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.SendToConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, Activity activity, Dictionary 2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.SendToConversationAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

For BadRequest:-
`at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(ConversationParameters parameters, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.CreateConversationAsync(IConversations operations, ConversationParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see more information in your bot's channel blade (in Azure) for Teams?

Comment: Hello @DanaV, I found this message "User blocked the conversation with the bot" in azure channels for Teams as a warning.

Comment: I don't think i've seen that one before. Do you have AppInsights setup for your bot? If so, can you check logs and see what the exceptions say there? Typically query something like `exceptions 
| where timestamp > ago(24h) 
| limit 10` assuming you have the issue in the last 24 hours (or alter the query)

Comment: Are you sure the -same- message is being sent to all the users? Is it personalized in some way? If so, perhaps there's something about the particular personalization. Is it failing for the same users in the same way each time?

Comment: Hello @HiltonGiesenow, It is the same message that we are sending to everyone. I just added the error that I am getting for the Forbidden and Bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.10.2`

Microsoft recently released updates bo the Bot.Builder library. I've seen errors like this with the PowerBI API Library when not using a recent version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/4.10.2

You could also try to add the following before the call to `CreateConversationAsync()`:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(ServiceUrl, DateTime.MaxValue);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.appcredentials.trustserviceurl?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Comment: Hello @vvv4d, I am using `                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
` and `CreateConversationAsync(ConversationParameters)` and Bot.Builder4.8.0. Can you please help me in detail how to use `CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync` .

Comment: @Krishna089 sorry I mentioned the wrong method, continue you'd continue using `CreateConversationAsync() `.

Answer (score 0):

1. The message "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'" is returned whenever a user proactively blocks the bot contact (e.g. right click the contact or app in Teams -> "Block").
   In such case, the channel logs in the Azure portal should also report the message: "User blocked the conversation with the bot".
2. The message "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'" is trickier to be solved; in my experience, it is generally related to some payload that is not supported by the Teams channel: e.g. an unsupported property in an AdaptiveCard, or an improperly formatted URL in an OpenUrl action. My suggestion is to test any AdaptiveCard content by using the Card Editor in the App Studio Teams application, before posting it to real conversations. It might be quite tricky to find what's causing the issue, otherwise.